# Can I use populate before aggregate in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two models, one is user

```js
 userSchema = new Schema({
     userID: String,
     age: Number
 });
```

and the other is the score recorded several times everyday for all users

```js
 ScoreSchema = new Schema({
     userID: {type: String, ref: 'User'},
     score: Number,
     created_date = Date,
     ....
 })
```

I would like to do some query/calculation on the score for some users meeting specific requirement, say I would like to calculate the average of score for all users greater than 20 day by day.

My thought is that firstly do the **populate** on Scores to populate user's ages and then do the **aggregate** after that.

Something like

```js
Score.
    populate('userID','age').
    aggregate([
        {$match: {'userID.age': {$gt: 20}}},
        {$group: ...},
        {$group: ...}
    ], function(err, data){});
```

Is it Ok to use populate before aggregate? Or I first find all the userID meeting the requirement and save them in a array and then use $in to match the score document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you cannot call `.populate()` before `.aggregate()`, and there is a very good reason why you cannot. But there are different approaches you can take.

The `.populate()` method works "client side" where the underlying code actually performs additional queries ( or more accurately an `$in` query ) to "lookup" the specified element(s) from the referenced collection.

In contrast `.aggregate()` is a "server side" operation, so you basically cannot manipulate content "client side", and then have that data available to the aggregation pipeline stages later. It all needs to be present in the collection you are operating on.

A better approach here is available with MongoDB 3.2 and later, via the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operation. Also probably best to handle from the `User` collection in this case in order to narrow down the selection:

```js
User.aggregate(
    [
        // Filter first
        { "$match": {
            "age": { "$gt": 20 } 
        }},
        // Then join
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "scores",
            "localField": "userID",
            "foriegnField": "userID",
            "as": "score"
        }},
        // More stages
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
)
```

This is basically going to include a new field "score" within the `User` object as an "array" of items that matched on "lookup" to the other collection:

```js
{
    "userID": "abc",
    "age": 21,
    "score": [{
        "userID": "abc",
        "score": 42,
        // other fields
    }]
}
```

The result is always an array, as the general expected usage is a "left join" of a possible "one to many" relationship. If no result is matched then it is just an empty array.

To use the content, just work with an array in any way. For instance, you can use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator in order to just get the single first element of the array in any future operations. And then you can just use the content like any normal embedded field:

```js
        { "$project": {
            "userID": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "score": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$score", 0 ] }
        }}
```

If you don't have MongoDB 3.2 available, then your other option to process a query limited by the relations of another collection is to first get the results from that collection and then use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) to filter on the second:

```js
// Match the user collection
User.find({ "age": { "$gt": 20 } },function(err,users) {

    // Get id list      
    userList = users.map(function(user) {
       return user.userID;
    });

    Score.aggregate(
        [ 
            // use the id list to select items
            { "$match": {
                "userId": { "$in": userList }
            }},
            // more stages
        ],
        function(err,results) {

        }
    );

});
```

So by getting the list of valid users from the other collection to the client and then feeding that to the other collection in a query is the onyl way to get this to happen in earlier releases.

Comment: if userList is an array of objectId do you have to convert them to strings

Comment: you're a smart guy but `foriegnField` should be `foreignField` I think. no big deal