# populate then aggreagate in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I really wanted to populate then aggregate

```
    Comps.find().populate({
        path : "reviews",
        model : "Review"
    }).exec(function(err, populatedData){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log("populatedData--", populatedData)
    }).aggregate([
        {$unwind : "$reviews"}
    ]).exec(function(err, doc){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("statements from aggregate", doc)
    })
```

I add an object id of a review into the `reviews` array of the Comps collection when ever the user makes a review. and now I am populating the reviews inside Comps. I wanted to do aggregate stuff on the reviews.

I see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119717/can-i-use-populate-before-aggregate-in-mongoose) I cant do it because of client side and server side stuff but I don't know how to fix it.

In the link, the answer is basically making its own populate method for putting together the collection? when he uses `$lookup`?

This is one of the docs from `> db.comps.find().pretty()`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("579706567f9c8cbc07482e65"),
        "name" : "comp1",
        "industry" : "industry1",
        "anonUsers" : [ ],
        "users" : [ ],
        "reviews" : [
                "57ad8c4353ef022423dcdadb",
                "57ad98e5cdc0ec7009530519",
                "57ad997e51c65ab8283d9c19",
                "57ad99f3480d0ffc141ffdf3",
                "57ad9aafcba3fb3029b22b19",
                "57ad9b953643bbb428034966",
                "57ad9d022ac828040b51f824",
                "57ad9d362bd44db8226efd47",
                "57ad9e6f000e02082adf1110",
                "57ad9fa3e4c8a91c20e8b805",
                "57ada040717ddc10250b2255",
                "57ada069e3f0f96422253364",
                "57adf85d6312904c0ee62ae5",
                "57adfce8b9be606007c073b1",
                "57adff001600b53c0fe74d35"
        ],
        "__v" : 16
}
```

here is one for `db.reviews.find().pretty()`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57adff001600b53c0fe74d35"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-12T16:53:30.510Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-12T16:53:20.318Z"),
        "vote" : "up",
        "reviewText" : "coolio again",
        "company" : ObjectId("579706567f9c8cbc07482e65"),
        "companyName" : "comp1",
        "userType" : "anon",
        "user" : ObjectId("57adfef51600b53c0fe74d34"),
        "statements" : [
                {
                        "name" : "statement3",
                        "question" : "This is the question for statement3",
                        "result" : 8
                },
                {
                        "name" : "statement4",
                        "question" : "This is the question for statement4",
                        "result" : 7
                },
                {
                        "name" : "statement6",
                        "question" : "This is the question for statement6",
                        "result" : 6
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 1,
        "className" : "thisUser",
        "momented" : "a few seconds ago"
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried doing this from the link. It just gives me the comps and the reviews is a list of ids. `reviews` should be an array of objects. The objects should be the reviews from the `reviews` collection. Like population

```
Comps.aggregate([
    {"$lookup": {
        "from" : "Reviews",
        "localField" : "_id",
        "foreignField": "_id", 
        "as": "returndComp"
    }}
], function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("result", result)
})
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of a few of the input documents?

Comment: I added something to the question. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the linked answer stated, you can't do `populate()` then `aggregate()` but you can certianly use **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** to achieve what you need. Because `reviews` is an array, you'll need to add an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** stage to your pipeline.

The extra **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** stage at the end is to flatten the array field from the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline.

The following example shows this:

```
Comps.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$reviews" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Reviews",
            "localField": "reviews",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "review"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$review" },
]).exec(function(err, doc){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("statements from aggregate", doc)
});
```

Comment: `console.log("statements from aggregate", doc)` gives me an empty array.. `statements from aggregate []` .. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've changed the setting for the `from` key of the `$lookup` operator from `"from": "reviews",` to `"from": "Reviews",` since that's what you wrote as the underlying collection name in your `aggregate()` attemtpt. Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: the collections name is `reviews` there is no collection called `Reviews` I'm assuming you changed it to that because you saw my edit in the question. I think it should be `reviews`. I get the  same empty array.

Comment: TLDR  basically there is difference between the amount of reviews for the company and the reviews in the reviews array in the `comps` collection...

I don't know if this makes a difference but for example for comp1 i had alot of reviews(so that made alot of docs in the reviews collection). then I implemented that when ever  someone enters a review for comp1 send the id for that review to the array , `reviews` in comp1 in the `comps` collection. before I didn't do that. just saying.

Comment: I see `reviews: '57adff001600b53c0fe74d35',`after the unwind and `ObjectId("57adff001600b53c0fe74d35"),` in the reviews collection for the id so when it goes to `"localField" : "reviews",` it sees a string and not an objectId. maybe something like that is a problem?

Comment: I think I got it it to work. I set up the schema a while ago and i forgot that I set the type of reviews elements  to `String` now I did `reviews : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Review"}],` and it looks like it works. Thanks.